# extract numbers or words before any special characters in unix shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have some thing like this in a variable

```
10> 100 1000= 110
```

I would like to extract 10 and 1000 from this( 1st number before any special character given). The special characters mentioned here might change so this should work with any special characters like >,<,=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gnu grep` with `-oP` (PCRE) regex:

```
s='10> 100 1000=110'
grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=[<>=])' <<< "$s"

10
1000
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `[0-9]+`: Match one or more digits
- `(?=[<>=])`: Lookahead to assert there is a `<` or `>` or `=` characters ahead

Comment: Thanks U saved me :)

Comment: what can we do if we what to add alphabets [a-zA-Z] in lookahead

Comment: `grep -oP '[0-9]+(?=[<>=a-zA-Z])' <<< "$s"`

Comment: one more doubt what if we want to extract 100 and 110 which are after special characters in that string.

Comment: For that you can use `grep -oP '[<>=]\s+\K[0-9]+' file`